# Flutter Image.Network not rebuiling/triggering api call when url value is changed

Tags: flutter, dart

The title essentially sums up the issue I'm having. In the code below you can see that I have a text field controller assigned to the URL input. I'm wanting the effect to be that when the user finishes entering a URL the image is automatically updated. In my case, the image never updates after the field value is changed. However, the image does change once a hot reload is performed. Only then is the desired effect achieved. What's going on here? I would assume that on every change to the Text controllers value that the entire form would be rebuilt(which I do see when I enable rainbow flag in dev tools) except for the image widget. Why is this happening?

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class EditProductPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/edit-product-page';
  @override
  _EditProductPageState createState() => _EditProductPageState();
}

class _EditProductPageState extends State<EditProductPage> {
  final _urlTextController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Edit Product'),
      ),
      body: Card(
        elevation: 5,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
          child: Form(
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Price'),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Description'),
                  maxLines: 3,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                ),
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: 100,
                      height: 100,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 8,
                        right: 10,
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                          width: 1,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: _urlTextController.text.isEmpty
                          ? Text('Enter a URL')
                          : FittedBox(
                              child: Image.network(
                                _urlTextController.text,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                key: ValueKey(_urlTextController.text),
                              ),
                            ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Image URL'),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                        controller: _urlTextController,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you ever get this?  I have I think the same issue.  If I force a page rebuild by navigation to another page and back, it updates.  But setState() doesn't help to tell my Image.network() to rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change state every time user inputs something to rebuild form with new values

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    _urlTextController.addListener(onUrlChanged);
    super.initState();
  }
  
  void onUrlChanged() {
    setState(() {});
  }
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _urlTextController.removeListener(onUrlChanged);
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `onChanged` callback which will trigger after adding anything inside TextFormField

```
    Expanded(
            child: TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Image URL'),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                controller: _urlTextController,
              onChanged: (value) {
                if (value.contains('.png')) { // Add ||(or) condition like this for other extension
                  setState(() {});
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: @Jared Rieger: Could you accept the answer if it helps you, its good practice where we accept the answer so that other devs can find this useful